# Compute MD5 digest of file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, md5

Using Haskell, how can I compute the MD5 digest of a file without using external tools like `md5sum`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [cryptonite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptonite) nowadays:

```
import System.Environment
import Crypto.Hash
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = do
  content <- L.readFile "foo.txt"

  let digest = hashlazy content :: Digest MD5

  putStrLn $ show digest
```

(You can actually replace `MD5` with any hash algorithm cryptonite supports, `SHA256` for instance.)

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use the [`pureMD5`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pureMD5) package, for example if you want to compute the hash of the file `foo.txt`:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import Data.Digest.Pure.MD5

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileContent <- LB.readFile "foo.txt"
    let md5Digest = md5 fileContent
    print md5Digest
```

This code prints the the same MD5 sum as `md5sum foo.txt`.

If you prefer a one-liner, you can use this one (the imports are the same as above):

```
LB.readFile "foo.txt" >>= print . md5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using [`cryptohash`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cryptohash) which is based on a C implementation and also provides other hashes algorithms like SHA1:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
import Crypto.Hash

md5 :: LB.ByteString -> Digest MD5
md5 = hashlazy

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileContent <- LB.readFile "foo.txt"
    let md5Digest = md5 fileContent
    print $ digestToHexByteString md5Digest
```