# Deterministic Generation of UUID in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a deterministic way to get UUID from a datatype, like I always get the same UUID...

`myItem -> UUID`

Comment: If `MyItem` is an instance of `Generic`, we can implement something like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Hashable-Generic.html but then to an `UUID` instead of an `Int`.

Comment: FWIW, `fromWords` deterministically converts from four `Word32` values to `UUID`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hash the data with a Hash that is at least 128 bits then use `Data.Binary.decode :: ByteString -> UUID`.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
    build-depends: base, binary, uuid-types, cryptohash-sha256, bytestring
-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Binary (decode,encode,Binary)
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 (hashlazy)
import Data.UUID.Types
import GHC.Generics
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (fromStrict)

data Foo = Foo Int String
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Generic,Binary)

main :: IO ()
main = print (decode @UUID (fromStrict (hashlazy (encode (Foo 1 "hello")))))
```

And:

```
chmod +x so.hs ; ./so.hs
...
f32f6f68-2131-8c5e-babd-f7e1dc190163
```

Comment: This doesn't set the version and variant fields correctly. A UUID isn't just a random 128-bit value. Even a randomly-generated UUID should have a version of 4 and a variant of 1. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) for details.

Comment: If you accidentally generate a variant 2 UUID (with a 1/8 probability) the hex representation will be little-endian, which is confusing because it doesn't match the byte order in memory and the hex representation you get from a naive conversion of the 16 bytes to hex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the UUID is what you need. An UUID is as its name says universally unique, so you should not be getting the same UUID twice (or at least the probability of this happening is negligible).

What you probably need is a [hashing method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), Haskell has surely support for most of these functions

--- EDIT ---

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536583/compute-md5-digest-of-file-in-haskell) question for a way of computing a hash out of a file. I think you can easily adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Some UUIDs are more deterministic than others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions_3_and_5_(namespace_name-based) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122#section-4.3 https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID-V5.html

Comment: @julodnik, I need a UUID... now that it requires an intermediary hash make sense to me... but I don't know how you could guess I don't need a UUID....

Comment: @MichałPolitowski, yeah I have seen this link, but I don't understand how I could use it so far...

Comment: @NicolasHenin: I guess you don't need a UUID, because semantically an UUID is used as an unique identifier which guarantees uniqueness when properly generated. If you want it to depend on a certain data then it is not unique anymore. It might look like a UUID but it is not anymore. The definition of what you need is a hash function. You can of course format the hash to look like an UUID but it will still not be a UUID.

Comment: I don't follow your logic @julodnik ... It's a well known concept called Deterministic UUID.... if it's translated from a Hash to a UUID, at the end this is a UUID.... a UUID is a format...

Comment: UUID is a thing that's unique across time and space. By `myItem -> UUID` as a pure function breaks those guarantees. Please add "Need UUID format - not it's guarantees" to the question for clarification.

Comment: @przemo_li Like a UUID, a hash is also probabilistically unique.  If `myItem` hashes to the same value and thus the same UUID.  It is still pseudo-random as asked for by the RFC and it is still universally unique.  Specifically see section 4.3 of RFC 4122 as well as the uniqueness considerations in section 3.

Comment: In other words: "unique across time" is actually not a defining characteristic of UUID these days, quoting the RFC "The UUIDs generated at different times from the same name in the same namespace MUST be equal.".

Answer (score 1):

Pick sufficiently unique set of attributes of `myItem` - generate hash - you got your UUID. Chance of clashing hashes depend of course on hash algorithm and quality of attributes you pick.

Comment: `fromString` may be useful: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to create the UUID from another value, it should be a [v5 value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions_3_and_5_(namespace_name-based)) with the version and variant fields set correctly. This is produced by hashing a namespace and a name, and you would use [Data.UUID.V5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid/docs/Data-UUID-V5.html)  to generate it:

```hs
import Data.Binary (encode, Binary)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (unpack)
import Data.UUID
import Data.UUID.V5

-- A randomly-generated v4 UUID
namespaceBinary :: UUID
namespaceBinary = fromWords 0xfa31c246 0x3353498a 0xb2ca29f4 0x79cfcc0b

uuidFromBinary :: Binary a => a -> UUID
uuidFromBinary = generateNamed namespaceBinary . unpack . encode
```

The namespace UUID is a fixed value that you would define once and use consistently (eg by always using `uuidFromBinary`).