# Haskell: Install pureMD5 package

Tags: haskell, md5, cabal

I am trying to tell whether two files are likely the same, and found I could make a MD5 hash in Haskell from this StackOverflow thread: [Compute MD5 digest of file in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536583/compute-md5-digest-of-file-in-haskell)

When I try to install [pureMD5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pureMD5), I get an error:

```
$ cabal install --lib pureMD5
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (user goal)
[__1] trying: ghc-8.6.5/installed-8.6... (user goal)
[__2] next goal: process (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: process-1.6.6.0 (conflict: ghc =>
process==1.6.5.0/installed-1.6...)
[__2] rejecting: process-1.6.5.1, process-1.6.5.0/installed-1.6...,
process-1.6.5.0, process-1.6.4.0, process-1.6.3.0, process-1.6.2.0,
process-1.6.1.0, process-1.6.0.0, process-1.5.0.0, process-1.4.3.0,
process-1.4.2.0, process-1.4.1.0, process-1.4.0.0, process-1.3.0.0,
process-1.2.3.0, process-1.2.2.0, process-1.2.1.0, process-1.2.0.0,
process-1.1.0.2, process-1.1.0.1, process-1.1.0.0, process-1.0.1.5,
process-1.0.1.4, process-1.0.1.3, process-1.0.1.2, process-1.0.1.1,
process-1.0.0.0 (constraint from user target requires ==1.6.6.0)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: ghc, process)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: process, base, ghc
```

I am not sure where to go from here, I'm new to Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cabal issue unrelated to pureMD5 (I believe).  You can try to install with a different environment as:

```
cabal new-install --package-env=SomeNewEnv --lib pureMD5
```

And that should work.  But why? well the environment you currently have installed packages into looks something like this:

```
cat ~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.6.4/environments/default | tail
package-id rts
package-id terminfo-0.4.1.2
package-id transformers-0.5.6.2
package-id deepseq-1.4.4.0
package-id ghc-boot-th-8.6.4
package-id pretty-1.1.3.6
package-id template-haskell-2.14.0.0
package-id directory-1.3.3.0
package-id txt-1.2.4.0-09ee5c37
package-id mtl-2.2.2
```

So you see it fixes a particular package version - for you it probably keeps process-1.6.5.0.  If you remove this file then the attempted install of process-1.6.6.0 will succeed and the install will work without the `--package-env`.

Again, this is a guess based on the error and what I think your system state is - please do test and report back.

EDIT: For the curious the bug is https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5559

Comment: while it works, I don't understand what the consequences are - it would help if I better understood how cabal works, and what `cabal new-install` does ... it seems like cabal works within "environments" or projects, and I wonder what the consequences are of running `new-install`...

Comment: `new-install` and `install` are the same on sufficiently new versions of `cabal` so I shouldn't have mentioned it.

Consequences:  GHC and cabal uses an environment to keep a list of packages you have "exposed" - these packages must not conflict (no duplicate packages with different versions).  When you `cabal install` you are saying "install this library and expose it in my default environment". Something you already installed uses a package with a different version than what you want to install now.

Because GHC envs are pointers to builds it is reasonable to rm the env as desired.