# I can't install the library gloss, in Mac OS Catalina (Haskell)

Tags: macos, haskell, macos-catalina, gloss

I am trying to **install the [Haskell gloss library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss)**, on Mac OS Catalina, but I have a lot of problems.

I download the tar.gz file from that page.

The first thing I did was follow [this](https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) steps to install Haskell.

Already with **cabal installed** (the previous link downloads it), I used this command `cabal install gloss`. But report the following error:

```
❯ cabal install gloss                                                                                 
  Resolving dependencies...
  cabal: Cannot build the executables in the package gloss because it does not
  contain any executables. Check the .cabal file for the package and make sure
  that it properly declares the components that you expect.
```

I already did `cabal update`. And then again `cabal install gloss`, but nothing.

Then I did `cabal v2-update`, all okey. And `cabal v2-install --lib gloss`, but here the report was:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually download a tarball.  Just `cabal v2-update && cabal v2-install --lib gloss`.  Notice the `v2-` prefix is default in cabal version 3.0 or higher, I'm just including it here in case you are using an old cabal.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I have just edit the question with what you told me, there is the report.

Comment: Ah, this is horrible [bug in cabal](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5559) but there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755666/haskell-install-puremd5-package).

Comment: Maybe it will work on stack?